# Showing "unavailable" pavucontrol audio profile in system sound settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have Intel NUC, which has  3.5 mm jack and I have two screens connected to it. In system sound settings, I see only the two screens as possible outputs. When I open pavucontrol Configuration tab, among the Built-in Audio profiles, I have "Analogue Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable)" and "Analogue Stereo Duplex (unavailable)" + loads of HDMI related items. When I choose one of the former options, sound goes through the 3.5 mm jack.

I want to easily switch between the screen and jack outputs. How do I make those pavucontrol profiles available in the system sound output menu?